# JObject nested property

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to make a json object like this with JObject:

```
{
    "input": {
        "webpage/url": "http://google.com/"
    }
}
```

I can add properties like:

```
JObject job = new JObject(
                new JProperty("website/url", "http://www.google.com") );
```

But any time I try to nest an object inside another object so I can have the parent "input" it throws an exception.

How do you make nested properties with JObject?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Probably the most straightforward way would be:

```
var input = new JObject();

input.Add("webpage/url", "http://google.com");

var obj = new JObject();

obj.Add("input", input);
```

Which gives you:

```
{
  "input": {
    "webpage/url": "http://google.com"
  }
}
```

Another way would be:

```
var input = new JObject
{
    { "webpage/url", "http://google.com" }
};

var obj = new JObject
{
    { "input", input }
};
```

... Or if you wanted it all in one statement:

```
var obj = new JObject
{
    {
        "input",
        new JObject
        {
            { "webpage/url", "http://google.com" }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: This is indeed much more straightforward :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe: Nothing wrong with yours either... Just a matter of taste

Answer (score 7):

Just carry on as you are, and nest them in another level:

```
JObject job = new JObject(
                new JProperty("website/url", "http://www.google.com") );

JObject parent = new JObject(new JProperty("input", job));
```

`parent.ToString()` now gives:

> {   "input": {
>       "website/url": "http://www.google.com"   } }

Comment: I used a subtly different approach that did away with the intermediate assignment: ` JObject parent = new JObject() {
     new JProperty("input",
      new JObject() {
       new JProperty("website/url", "http://w w w.google.com")
      }
     )
     }; `