# Adding a properties to JSON that is missing

Tags: c#

So I have been working on JSON files over the past few days, just to understand how C# can manipulate JSON.

I need some help with adding a property to a JSON file. I have figured out how to edit values through trial and error, however, I had assumed that it would create the path where I access the value. Turns out this isn't the case.

This is what I currently have done with regards to access a values Height and Width, however, there is no "externalSite""Weblogin""window" path within the JSON

```
string widthBox = Width.Text.ToString();
string heightBox = Height.Text.ToString();

string CustomSizejson = File.ReadAllText(DownloadConfigFilelocation);
JObject CustomSizeobj = JObject.Parse(CustomSizejson);
CustomSizeobj["externalSite"]["webLogin"]["window"] = "height=" + heightBox + ",width=" + widthBox + ",resizable,scrollbars";
string CustomSizenewJson = CustomSizeobj.ToString();
File.WriteAllText(DownloadConfigFilelocation, CustomSizenewJson);
```

This is pretty much what I want to accomplish and append it to the JSON file

[image: EXPECTED RESULT]

Can someone help me figure this out? 
Thanks

Comment: You need to create the objects in the JSON tree one by one. They’re not created automatically when you try to access them

Comment: Yeah I realized this - Trying to figure out the way to implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add property using `JObject.Add` function. Example:

```
JObject json = new JObject();
json.Add("property_name", "property_value");
```

If you want to add something not exactly object but inside some property of it.
You first need to find property itself and use `JObject.Add` function. Example:

```
JObject inner_json = (JObject) json["property_name"];
inner_json.Add("inner_property_name","value");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
var input = new JObject();
input.Add("window", "height=300,width=410,resizable,scrollbars");

var obj = new JObject();
obj.Add("webLogin", input);

var obj1 = new JObject();
obj1.Add("externalSite", obj);
```

For more information:
[JObject nested property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30126167/jobject-nested-property)